# About the sql performance of select ... in

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql 5.7.21

I use pool to connect database and run the SQL

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let pool = mysql.createPool(db);
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
      if(err){
        ...
      }else{
        console.log('allConnections:' + pool._allConnections.length);
        let q = conn.query(sql, val, (err, rows,fields) => {
        ...
```

I have a table with around 1,000,000 records.  I wrote a select to fecth the records.

```
select * from tableA where trackingNo in (?)
```

I will send the trackingNo via array param. The amount of trackingNo is around 20000. It means the length of array is around 20000.

And I made the index to trackingNo column. (trackingNo column is varchar type, not unique, can be null, blank and all possible values)

The problem is, I find it will cost around 5 minutes to get the results! 5 minutes here means purely backend sql handling time. I think it is too slow to match 20000 records in 1,000,000 records. Do you have any suggestion for select.. in ?

Explain SQL:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys          key    key_len   ref   rows   filtered   Extra
1   SIMPLE      tableA  null        ALL     table_tracking_no_idx  null   null      null  999507    50      Using where
```

Comment: Table definition would help,edit your question.Do you have an index on trackingNo?Are the trackingNos contiguous?Is trackingNo unique?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `EXPLAIN` for that query?

Comment: Not a suggestion for your specific query, but using `EXPLAIN SELECT` usually explains the issue. https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-mysql-queries-with-explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider populating a table with the tracking numbers you want to match.  Then, you could use an inner join instead of your current `WHERE IN` approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tbl b
    ON a.trackingNo = b.trackingNo;
```

This has the advantage that you may index the new `tbl` table on the `trackingNo` column to make the join lookup extremely fast.

This assumes that `tbl` would have a single column `trackingNo` which contains the 20K+ values you need to consider.

Comment: Thx @Tim, let me try it.

Comment: Thx @Tim, I have tried. Yes, the performance is highly imporved after using the temp table. thx again.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL creates a binary search tree for `IN` lists that are composed of constants.  As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

> If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This means IN is very quick if the IN value list consists entirely of constants.

In general, creating a separate table with constants does not provide much improvement in performance.

I suppose there could be some subtle issue with type compatibility -- such as collations -- that interferes with this process.

This type of query probably requires a full table scan.  If the rows are wide, then the combination of the scan and returning the data may be accounting for the performance.  I do agree that five minutes is a long time, but it could be entirely due to the network connection between the app/GUI and the database.

Comment: @thx Gordon. 5 minutes here means purely backend sql handling time. From the beginning of execution sql to the end. I not sure it is caused by collations issue. Because the column is varchar type. And the data contains null, blank and other possible values, such as  null, '', 'SD231', '2324423' etc. Obviously, the column is not unique. And I create the ASC index for it. Will it be the array param issue or any other Mysql setting trick?